# Checking for specific number of rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Wasn't sure how to title this issue but a little story behind will give you a clearer understanding, I hope.

So I'm trying to check records and always expecting to see four rows.
Some records have only 3, what is the best way to check those records that are missing a row? Loop? If statement? I just need a suggestion not a solution. I want to work it out myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A count with a having clause is probably the approach, but you have not provided any details / schema to work with.

```
SELECT count(*), someFieldYouGroupOn
FROM someTable
GROUP BY someFieldYouGroupOn
HAVING count(*) <> 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll play with this and see how I get on.

Comment: If you need more open ended / iterative advice, the SQL chat on the chat rooms is better placed to help.

Answer (score 0):

because you add plsql tag tou can do the below

```
set serveroutput on size 1000
/
declare cnt number (8);
begin
select count(1) into cnt from ex_employee2;
if (cnt <4) then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The count is less then '||cnt);
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll play with this and see how I get on.